trying to know how can i implement my custom preset values for props to suggest in vscode when using component
my question is straight forward i am attaching a screenshot take a look at auto suggestions in vscode that is offering some preset values from Radix Ui library
my question is how can i achieve similar functionality while creating my own component in react
i researched a bit and got some clue about typescript implementation which i personally dont know much about hope its not typescript specific feature do explain please if anybody know about this
Note i have no extension intalled for radix its just working

